# In Java is there any method to read a data of a line from file?

Tags: java

Is there a method to read the first and the last data from a line which are separated by space from a file in java. 
Example:
the file contains the following information

```
100 20-11-2020 08:25:42 IN
101 21-09-2020 09:01:20 IN
```

Here I just want 100 and IN to extract and print

Comment: Here's a hint: Search for "String to array" then look for "get first and last item of array"

Comment: Here's another hint: Try doing it first with dummy data and without the file. Once that's done, you can worry about the I/O part

Comment: Yes, divide and conquer. 2 steps here: 1 read the file line by line (BufferedReader or Scanner can do this) and 2) `String#split(...)` to get the "tokens" within the line.

Comment: I suggest following a tutorial if you're trying to get into Java by yourself or reading your course again if you're doing this in the context of academics. That problem is fairly basic and it feels like giving you the straight answer wouldn't be helpful in the long run. If you want pointers, you can look at the javadoc of the `Files` (with an s) and `String` classes, they contain two methods that are enough to solve your problem (they do contain a lot of other methods though) as long as you're familiar with arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to read the entire string and use the split method. Store the split string in an array and simply access the first and last element., something like this:

```
String line = "100 20-11-2020 08:25:42 IN"
String arr[] = line.split(" ");
String var1 = arr[0];//stores 100
String var2 = arr[arr.length - 1];//stores IN
```

Hope that helps! Happy coding!